# Is RVO allowed when a copy constructor is private and not implemented?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rvo

Suppose I have a class where the copy constructor is private and *not implemented* (to make the object non-copyable)

```
class NonCopyable {
// whatever
 private:
    NonCopyable( const NonCopyable&);
    void operator=(const NonCopyable&);
 };
```

Now in some member function of the same class I write code that returns an object of that class:

```
NonCopyable NonCopyable::Something()
{
    return NonCopyable();
}
```

which is a case when RVO could kick in.

RVO still requires that a copy constructor is accessible. Since the possible call to the copy constructor is done from within the same class member function the copy constructor *is accessible*. So technically RVO is possible despite the fact that the intent was to prohibit using the copy constructor.

Is RVO allowed in such cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is quite interesting.

This is the typical C++03 declaration.

```
class NC {
public:
    NC NC::Something() {
        return NC();
    }

private:
    NC(NC const&);
    NC& operator=(NC const&);
};
```

Here, as noted, RVO may kick in even though we semantically wanted to *avoid* copying.

In C++03, the solution is to delegate:

```
class NC: boost::noncopyable {
public:
    NC NC::Something() { // Error: no copy constructor
        return NC();
    }
};
```

In C++11, we have the alternative of using the `delete` keyword:

```
class NC {
public:
    NC NC::Something() { // Error: deleted copy constructor
        return NC();
    }

private:
    NC(NC const&) = delete;
    NC& operator=(NC const&) = delete;
};
```

But sometimes, we want to prevent copy, but would like to allow *Builder* (as in the Pattern).

In this case, your example works *as long as RVO kicks in*, which is a bit annoying as it is, in essence, non-standard. A definition of the copy constructor should be provided but you wish it not to be used.

In C++11, this usecase is supported by deleting copy operations and defining move operations (even privately).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, RVO would be allowed in this case - at least if the caller of `Something()` was a class member or friend.

I think this is one reason why private inheritance of a non-copyable class is better than doing it 'manually' in each class you want to prevent copying in.  In that case there's no accidental loophole.

For example, using `boost::noncopyable`:

```
class NonCopyable : private boost::noncopyable {
public:
    NonCopyable() {};
    NonCopyable Something();
};

NonCopyable NonCopyable::Something()
{
    return NonCopyable();  // causes compile time error, not link time error
}
```

Comment: Or simply using C++11 `delete` facilities to clearly disambiguate right at the compilation stage (instead of the link stage) that the class shall not be copied.

Comment: @Matthieu: yes, that's a better mechanism if you don't have to worry about legacy compilers (I guess we can call them legacy already, even if I'm sure they still have vast dominance in usage).

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed, but you may get a link error because the copy constructor is not implemented.
If you provide a body for `NonCopyable( const NonCopyable&)`, it would work.

Comment: There would be no link error because with RVO there's no actual call to the copy ctor.

Comment: There _may be_ a link error :) E.g. if optimizations are turned off. I've got the error in MSVC even with optimizations on.

Comment: Michael is still right: There is no link error _if_ the Return Value Optimization has been done (which was the scenario discussed). That obviously implies that that particular optimization is not turned off.

Answer (score 0):

One important point may overshadow the actual question.

> What is the use case of such function if RVO is allowed ?

This function can be called in 3 ways and 2 of them will be a compiler error:

```
NonCopyable obj;
NonCopyable obj2 = obj; // 1 --> error
NonCopyable &r = obj;   // 2 --> error
const NonCopyable &rc = obj; // 3 --> ok, but dangerous (may lead to UB)
```

One can't use the returned object effectively, so it really doesn't matter if the RVO is allowed or not.